# parsing code-like data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP code which creates a python file out of some given code, executes it using some test cases, and grades the code based on how many test cases it passes. Note that every code example is a python function for some simple calculation.

```
<?php

if ($_POST["request_type"] === "release_grades") {
    $_POST["request_type"] = "get_answers";
    $answers = json_decode(very_simple_post_curl($back_address), TRUE);
    $_POST["request_type"] = "get_quiz";
    $questions = json_decode(very_simple_post_curl($back_address), TRUE);
    foreach ($answers as $index => $answer) {
        $answers[$index]["testcases"] = array();
        $answers[$index]["constraints"] = array();

        $data_original = $answer["AnswerText"];
        $question = $questions[$answer["TestQuestionID"]];

        $func_name = $question["QuestionFuncName"];
        $testcases = $question["testcases"];

        $answers[$index]["grade"] = $max_unscaled_grade = count($question["testcases"]);

        foreach ($testcases as $key => $value) {
            $data = $data_original . "\nprint(" . $func_name . $value["QuestionTestcaseArgs"] . ")";
            $fh = file_put_contents('test.py', $data);
            if ($fh === false)
                die();
            $output = trim(shell_exec("python test.py"));
            if ($output === $value["QuestionTestcaseReturn"]) {
                $answers[$index]["testcases"][$value["QuestionTestcaseID"]] = "PASSED";
            } else {
                $answers[$index]["testcases"][$value["QuestionTestcaseID"]] = "FAILED";
                $answers[$index]["grade"] --;
            }
        }
        $answers[$index]["grade"] /= $max_unscaled_grade;
        $answers[$index]["grade"] *= intval($question["TestQuestionPoints"]);
    }
}
```

Which iterates compares the result of some executed Python code with extracted test cases from the json below:

```
{"1":{"QuestionID":"1","QuestionDifficulty":"medium","QuestionText":"Write a function \"fibonacci\" that takes 1 integer parameter, n, which computes the fibonacci value for n.","QuestionFuncName":"fibonacci","testcases":[{"QuestionTestcaseID":"1","QuestionID":"1","QuestionTestcaseArgs":"(10, 10)","QuestionTestcaseReturn":"20"},{"QuestionTestcaseID":"2","QuestionID":"1","QuestionTestcaseArgs":"(3, 1)","QuestionTestcaseReturn":"4"},{"QuestionTestcaseID":"5","QuestionID":"1","QuestionTestcaseArgs":"(5)","QuestionTestcaseReturn":"5"},{"QuestionTestcaseID":"6","QuestionID":"1","QuestionTestcaseArgs":"(10)","QuestionTestcaseReturn":"55"}],"constraints":[{"QuestionConstraintID":"1","QuestionID":"1","QuestionConstraint":""}]}
```

However, I also have a function name for every code-input I execute, and before doing my test-case grading I want to see if the function names align, and modify the grade accordingly. How would I gather the function name from `$data`, so that I can compare it with `$func_name`?

EDIT:
`$data` looks like:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Comment: wow a PHP file that creates a Python file! Has computer science gone too far?

Comment: @Phiter sounds like a click bait ad you'd see on a terrible tech site.

Comment: You can use a regexp to capture the name after `def`.

Comment: I wasn't aware PHP had regex, my only experiences are with grep from bash. I found preg_match, but I can't understand what that returns. The syntax seems to be very similar to what I'm used to.

Comment: " I found preg_match, but I can't understand what that returns... http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php says `preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.`. So 1 if it matched, 0 if it didn't, false on error. Which part of that are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @ADyson I think I was confusing the return with the matches field. is `$func_check = preg_match('def .*(', $func_name);` what I'm looking for?